# proxy_pass in server-snippet annotation

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have an kubernetes ingress(nginx)

My ingress :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: backend-ingress-nginx
  annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
         set $abcde "ank";

      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
           proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$http_origin$request_uri";
           proxy_cache_valid 200 1h;
           proxy_cache_methods GET POST;
           proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
           location ~ (facadev2/api/v[0-9]+/info/getCourseDetailPage) {
                 proxy_cache akamai_sa_acp;
                 proxy_cache_valid 200 168h;
                 add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
                 proxy_pass http://facade-nodeport;

           }
spec:
  rules:
   - host: apis2.test.com
     http:
      paths:
      - path: /facadev2
        backend:
          serviceName: facade-nodeport
          servicePort: 80
```

Now the issue here is what should I use as proxy_pass in server-snippet. Currently it is giving error as :
**`[emerg] host not found in upstream "facade-nodeport" in /tmp/nginx-cfg929796726:450`**

Comment: Call this Pods which are exposed via facade-nodeport service.

Answer (score 0):

So, to reply exactly your question - yes, you are correct - it should be http://facade-nodeport and you specified it correct. Unfortunately I wasnt able to find right now, but if im not mistake - there was an limitation for regular Nginx ingress that allowed you only 1 rewrite/snippet section. More options were in paid Plus version. I will put this question as community support to easily edit this post in case of new info. Also i'll add justification url once find it.
Maybe this is an explanation in your situation.

What I can also propose - you can redo your ingress, put the `proxy_pass http://facade-nodeport;` away from snippet and add `facadev2/api/v[0-9]+/info/getCourseDetailPage` as a new path that will be mapped with facade-nodeport service.

smth like

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: backend-ingress-nginx
 annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
        set $abcde "ank";

     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
          proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$http_origin$request_uri";
          proxy_cache_valid 200 1h;
          proxy_cache_methods GET POST;
          proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
          location ~ (facadev2/api/v[0-9]+/info/getCourseDetailPage) {
                proxy_cache akamai_sa_acp;
                proxy_cache_valid 200 168h;
                add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
               

          }
spec:
 rules:
  - host: apis2.test.com
    http:
     paths:
     - path: /facadev2/api/v[0-9]+/info/getCourseDetailPage
       backend:
         serviceName: facade-nodeport
         servicePort: 80
```

I havent  reproduced this code, so please if you would try it - adapt correct syntax for  `/facadev2/api/v[0-9]+/info/getCourseDetailPage` and check what you have in the end in `nginx.conf` after applying.